# Get text from a table with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

With this code i am trying to extract text from a table called "Last matches" in this [webpage](https://s5.sir.sportradar.com/sports4africa/en/1/season/80526/headtohead/334075/340986/match/27195664)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


url = 'https://s5.sir.sportradar.com/sports4africa/en/1/season/80526/headtohead/334075/340986/match/27195664'
driver = webdriver.Edge("C:/Users/Hama/Documents/msedgedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//strong[text()='Last matches']/ancestor::div[6]//tbody/tr")))
rows= driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//strong[text()='Last matches']/ancestor::div[6]//tbody/tr")
All_last_matches = []
for res in rows:
   score = res.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[5]//div[@class=' no-wrap']").get_attribute("innerText")
   All_last_matches.append(score)
print(All_last_matches)
```

It gives me this list:

```
All_last_matches = ['2:0', '0:4', '3:4', '2:2', '0:1', '3:0', '2:0', '0:4', '1:0', '2:1', '1:1', '1:2']
```

How can i modify my code to get two lists like this:

```
Last_matches_team1 = ['2:0', '0:4', '3:4', '2:2', '0:1', '3:0']

Last_matches_team2 = ['2:0', '0:4', '1:0', '2:1', '1:1', '1:2']
```

I tried this:

```
Last_matches_team1 = All_last_matches[0:6]

Last_matches_team2 = All_last_matches[6:len(All_last_matches)]
```

But this will work only if the table1 have 6 rows, sometimes there is just 5 rows (5matches played)

Help is apprciated, thanks to all of you

Comment: Why don't you check the len first?

Comment: Even if i cheek the len of the list it will not help me, because i will not know from which index the result belongs to team2

Comment: Is there no way to differentiate the scores from the structure of the page/HTML?

Comment: The code provided isn't mine, thanks to @vitaliis for helping me creating it, i am newbie so that's why i don't know how to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in previous post, there are 2 tables so you need to treat them separately to get the lists you want

```
last_matches_team1 = []
last_matches_team2 = []

left_table = "(//table[@class='table'])[1]//tr[@class='cursor-pointer']//td[6]//div[@aria-label='Score']"
for row in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, (left_table)))):
    score = row.get_attribute("innerText")
    last_matches_team1.append(score)
print(last_matches_team1)

right_table = "(//table[@class='table'])[2]//tr[@class='cursor-pointer']//td[6]//div[@aria-label='Score']"
for row in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, (right_table)))):
    score = row.get_attribute("innerText")
    last_matches_team2.append(score)
print(last_matches_team2)
```

Prints:

```
['2:0', '0:4', '3:4', '2:2', '0:1', '3:0']
['2:0', '0:4', '1:0', '2:1', '1:1', '1:2']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `find_elemnts_by_xpath` using xpath `//strong[text()='Last matches']/ancestor::div[6]//following-sibling::tbody`

This will get you the 2 tables you need. Iterate through the collection by `find_element_by_tag_name("tr")` to get the respective table rows

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following `xpath` `//table[@class='table']` or `css_selector` `table[class='table']`
This wil give you exactly the 2 tables you are looking for.
Inside them you can clearly get the scores and put them into separate lists.